# Django save only first form of formset

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, modelform

I've looked through every similar question (and tried them), but still couldn't find answer.

I have two models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name = "Название проекта")
    url = models.URLField(max_length=120, unique=True, verbose_name = "Полный адрес сайта")
    robots_length = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse
        return reverse('projects:detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class ProjectPage(models.Model):
    page_project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page_url = models.URLField(verbose_name = "Адрес страницы")
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, verbose_name = "meta-title",default="")
    page_description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, verbose_name = "meta-description",default="")
    page_h1 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, verbose_name = "Заголовок h1",default="")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.page_url

    def __str__(self):
        return self.page_url
```

For each model there is a form:

```
class ProjectFormUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            "name",
            "url",
        ]
        widgets = {
           'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Произвольное название'}),
       }

class ProjectPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectPage
        fields = [
            'page_project',
            'page_url',
            'page_title',
            'page_description',
            'page_h1',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'page_project': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

In views.py I have:

```
def projects_update(request, proj=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Project, id=proj)
    form = ProjectFormUpdate(request.POST or None, instance=instance)

    formset_f = modelformset_factory(ProjectPage, form=ProjectPageForm, extra=3)
    formset = formset_f(queryset=ProjectPage.objects.filter(page_project__id=proj), initial =[{'page_project': proj}])

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = formset_f(request.POST)
        for formset_form in formset:
            if formset_form.is_valid() and formset_form.has_changed():
                formset_form.save()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {
        'title': "Редактируем проект - "+instance.name,
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
        'instance': instance,
        }
    return render(request, "projects_update.html", context)
```

And, finaly, html

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="create-form">
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-xs-10 offset-xs-1 form-bg">

        <h2>Общие данные</h2>

        {{ form|crispy}} 
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Обновить проект" />


    </div>
</div>

{% for formset_form in formset %}
<div class="row form-container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-xs-10 offset-xs-1 form-bg">
        <h3>Страница {{forloop.counter}}</h3>


        {{ formset_form|crispy}} 


    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}

</form>
```

What I am trying to achieve is: when user enters a page, he gets a form with project name and project URL already filled in. So, he can correct them.

Below, I want to show a filled in form for every page allready created for this project and several empty forms for creating new.

What happens is all initial data is displayed correctly, but when I fill several empty forms - only first empty form is saved each time.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to iterate through the formset forms to check validity and save them. Just do `if formset.is_valid(): formset.save()`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Changed my view to:
`if request.method == 'POST':
  formset = formset_f(request.POST)
  if formset.is_valid():
   formset.save()
  if form.is_valid():
   form.save()`. 
nothing is saved at all.

Comment: Well, the forms in the formset are probably not valid. Are you showing errors in the template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Not quite sure how valid it is but I have a block like this: `{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
     {% for message in messages %}
     <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}`

Another thing: if i fill in only one blank form it is saved. As soon as two or more are filled in - neither is saved.

Comment: @DanielRoseman figured it out, probably. Included formset.errors and it showed me that "page_project" (foreign key) for second to last blank form is missing. It's passed to first as "initial". What is the best way to pass it to every form?

Comment: @DanielRoseman another problem occured. Would much appreciate your advice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634990/django-formset-does-not-save-if-required-field-in-extra-form-is-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it was solved:

1. Included errors properly.
2. Saw that second to last form lack required field (hiddenInput)
3. Made changes in view so it looks like:

   ```
   formset_f = modelformset_factory(ProjectPage, form=ProjectPageForm, extra=3)

   formset = formset_f(queryset=ProjectPage.objects.filter(page_project__id=proj), initial =[{'page_project': proj}, {'page_project': proj}, {'page_project': proj}])
   ```

Initial values now match number of extra forms - every form got it's own foreign key.

Probably there is a better solution, but the the problem is found and solved for me!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when I tried to render every form of the formset manually I added an unneded `<form></form>` html element

wrong:

```
{ form.management_form }}

 {% for form in formset %}
   <form class="form-class">
       {{form.name}}
   </form>
```

right:

```
{ form.management_form }}

 {% for form in formset %}
   <div class="form-class">
       {{form.name}}
   </div>
```

After that change my forms were recognized correctly.